# Mamp Pro Restore root user / uninstall

Tags: mamp

Hi in Mamp Pro I accidentally removed the root account, so I now cannot use mysql to create new databases and all other operations.

This is the error I get when startng mysql via mamp pro:

Checking MySQL databases failed
Error message:
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqlcheck: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'mysql' when selecting the database

I have tried to reset to factory settings but that hasn't helped.

Basically in the users overview in Phpmyadmin, I just get a yellow box saying "No privileges".

I also tried to uninstall Mamp Pro, but when I tick the uninstaller's checkboxes and hit uninstall, I get the following error:

Error
The privileged action failed.

Help would be really appreciated since I cannot do any work like this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

MAMP evidently creates some configuration files that can't be wiped via the uninstaller. I was able to circumvent the `The privileged action failed` error and completely uninstall MAMP Pro using the following steps:

1. Delete the `appsolute` directory from `/Library/Application Support` , which contains configuration files that are created upon MAMP Pro installation
2. Delete the file `hosts.mamp.bak` in `/etc`, which is the MAMP hosts backup file
3. Delete the MAMP directory from `/Applications/MAMP`
4. Open the MAMP Pro Uninstaller, check all five options, and click to uninstall

This should completely wipe the existing MAMP/MAMP Pro installation and enable a clean, fresh install. You may need to restart your computer to get Apache running after re-installation.

Comment: FYI, it is also possible to recreate the `root` user without starting over.  You can start MySQL with a `--init-file` that grants permissions to the `root` user, eg: [Restoring a deleted root user](http://devlog.info/2010/10/12/restoring-a-deleted-mysql-root-user/).

Comment: I used CleanMyMac app in the end to completely remove Mamp.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Did you ever by chance narrow down the source of the error to one of the steps you listed above?

Comment: I followed instructions step by step, but unable to uninstall MAMP Pro I still get following error: The privileged action failed

OSX 10.9

Answer (score 0):

To remove MAMP from your computer, you can use a **your uninstaller** application. Once you've uninstalled MAMP, you can delete the MAMP folder located on your local disk C. and Then install again you will get the removed the root account.